# Javascript - Rearrange array elements in ascending order of elements within each array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, hashmap, nested

I have an array:

```
arr = 
[{"nid":"MIA","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},

{"nid":"MID","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]},

{"nid":"MIT","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"},{"sid":"sm4"},{"sid":"sm5"},{"sid":"sm6"},{"sid":"sm7"},{"sid":"sm8"},{"sid":"sm9"},{"sid":"sm10"}]},

{"nid":"MIO","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"}]},

{"nid":"MIS","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},

{"nid":"MIH","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]}]
```

`arr` consists of 6 elements. Each of these six elements consists of another array `keys`. I need to rearrange the six elements in ascending order of the number of keys within each. This means that I need the array to be rearranged in this manner:

```
arr = 
[

{"nid":"MID","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]},

{"nid":"MIH","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]},

{"nid":"MIA","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},

{"nid":"MIS","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},

{"nid":"MIO","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"}]},

{"nid":"MIT","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"},{"sid":"sm4"},{"sid":"sm5"},{"sid":"sm6"},{"sid":"sm7"},{"sid":"sm8"},{"sid":"sm9"},{"sid":"sm10"}]},
]
```

I tried to get the number of elements within `keys` of each array element as shown in the code below:

```
    var arrMap = [];
    arr.forEach(function(array_) {
        key_ = array_.keys;
        var count = 0;
        key_.forEach(function(arrKey) {
            count++;
            var keyCode = arrKey.sid;
        })
        arrMap.push({'nid':array_.nid, 'count': count});
    })
    console.log(arrMap);
```

This gave me the following output:

```
[{"nid":"MIA","count":2},{"nid":"MID","count":1},{"nid":"MIT","count":10},{"nid":"MIO","count":3},{"nid":"MIS","count":2},{"nid":"MIH","count":1}]
```

Now I am confused as to how I can proceed to rearrange the array using the `count` of key elements. Any guidance/help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `.sort`

```js
let arr = [ {"nid":"MIA","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},
{"nid":"MID","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]},
{"nid":"MIT","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"},{"sid":"sm4"},{"sid":"sm5"},{"sid":"sm6"},{"sid":"sm7"},{"sid":"sm8"},{"sid":"sm9"},{"sid":"sm10"}]},
{"nid":"MIO","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"},{"sid":"sm3"}]},
{"nid":"MIS","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"},{"sid":"sm2"}]},
{"nid":"MIH","keys":[{"sid":"sm1"}]} ];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.keys.length - b.keys.length);

console.log(arr);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **sort** function of array

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.keys.length - b.keys.length})
```